# Good References for Treasury Futures Spreads

Tags: fixed-income, interest-rates, futures, reference-request, spread

I’m reading the excellent [Treasury Bond Basis](https://www.mheducation.ca/professional/products/9780071456104/the+treasury+bond+basis/) by Burghardt. I was wondering if there’s a similar quality book/paper about Yield curve spreads using treasury futures (i.e. NOL, NOB, FYT).

Answer (score 4):

Im interested in this topic myself. I haven't found anything of a good standard yet. However, there are some pamphlets from CME that could be useful as an initial exploration. I will keep looking and improving this answer.

1. [Overview of Inter-Commodity Spreads for Interest Rate Products](https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/interest-rates/intercommodity-spread.html). CME Group
2. [Yield Curve Spread Trades: Opportunities & Applications](https://www.cmegroup.com/education/files/yield-curve-spread-trades.pdf). CME Group